# Cassandra multiple node setup

Tags: php, cassandra

I am new in Cassandra. I have installed cassandra on my windows system, and it works perfect but when i move to installed it on multiple node then it gives an error like :

```
>    error: Unknown keyspace system_traces
>-- StackTrace --
>java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown keyspace system_traces
>at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:273)
>at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:122)
>at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:99)
>at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.getRangesForEndpoint(StorageService.java:2856)
>at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.effectiveOwnership(StorageService.java:3772)
>at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.effectiveOwnership(StorageService.java:103)
>at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
>at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
>at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
>at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
>at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
>at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
>at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
>at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
>at >com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
>at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
>at >javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
>at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
>at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
>at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
>at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
>at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
>at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
>at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
>at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
>at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
>at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)'
```

Can any one guide me the step by step procedure to add multiple node.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, cassandra on windows having number of issues. May  be its better to reconsider using windows for cassandra

Comment: Here are the docs for adding a node to an existing cluster: [Adding nodes to an existing cluster](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html). Also make sure that you are running the same exact Cassandra version on each node. As @KarthikPrasad mentioned, Cassandra is not fully supported on Windows for production use, but should work well enough for dev/test.